# Multiple matches in a single string/line with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match all occurrences of {$anything} in a string.

An example string would be:

`Hello {$test} World`

Which works fine with:

```
^.*\{\$(.*?)\}.*$
```

or

```
preg_match("/^.*\{\$(.*?)\}.*$/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

But how do I loop this so it retrieves all the matches, for instance if I have:

`Hello {$test} World {$done}`

It only retrieves the last match into the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello {$test} World {$done}
    [1] => done
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all` with the correct regex to get all matches with: `{$...}` pattern

```
preg_match_all("/\{\$([^}]*)\}/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Then iterate through (process) `$output_array[1]`.

Comment: Great, I'm going to research a bit on your regex to see how it works.

Comment: Side notes: curly brackets don't need to be escaped, and if OP doesn't want to have to deal with match groups he can use lookarounds: `(?<={[$])[^}]*(?=})` ([explanation/example](http://regex101.com/r/dY7fT1)).

Comment: Okay, could you explain what this does? `[^}]`

Comment: @Devon that matches everything but a `}` (`[]` is a character class and `^` negates it).  This is preferred to `.*?` because instead of saying "lazily match 0+ characters" you say "match anything BUT `}`". TLDR: more specific